# Fullcalendar Scheduler - How can I get column border lines to display?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

The border is not displaying to segment the resource columns.

The highlighted areas below in red I would like to display the column divider.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've got some custom CSS which is messing with it. Did you use a pre made theme, or just change it yourself?

Comment: Although you provided no code, from the screenshot it would appear that the column divider is black (you can see it in the area around 9.30am and after 6pm) but the background is (mostly) black as well. Clearly that's a conflict. The obvious solution is to change one of the colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADyson was correct, thank you :)

The issue was a table CSS style that overrode the default fullcalendar CSS style

The fix for me was to remove :

```
table {
    background-color: #252526;
}
```